# Issues creating Json object on snowflake using Sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to Snowflake and I am trying to create a new table from an existing table and converting some rows into json format.

what I have on snowflake (table name: **lex)**

| area | source | type | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | modak | good | 2021 |

what I want to achieve on snowflake

| area | sources |
| --- | --- |
| One | [{"source": "modak","period": {"type": "good","date": "2021"} }] |

Any direction on how to go about it using SQl will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use object_construct to produce JSON objects:

```
select
area, array_construct( object_construct( 'source', source, 'period', object_construct( 'type',type, 'date',date )) ) sources
from
values ('One','modak','good','2021') tmp (area, source,type,date);

+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| AREA |                                 SOURCES                                 |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| One  | [ { "period": { "date": "2021", "type": "good" }, "source": "modak" } ] |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I also used array_construct to add the brackets ([])

OBJECT_CONSTRUCT:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_construct.html

ARRAY_CONSTRUCT:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_construct.html

PS: Order of the JSON elements are not important when accessing them:

```
select parse_json(j):source, parse_json(j):period.type 
from
values 
('{ "period": { "date": "2021", "type": "good" }, "source": "modak" }'),
('{"source": "modak","period": {"type": "good","date": "2021"} }') tmp(j);

+----------------------+---------------------------+
| PARSE_JSON(J):SOURCE | PARSE_JSON(J):PERIOD.TYPE |
+----------------------+---------------------------+
| "modak"              | "good"                    |
| "modak"              | "good"                    |
+----------------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: This is great @Gokhan, but is it possible if you could pls modify your code to produce the expected outcome

Comment: Do you mean you want to have the JSON elements in a different order? Unfortunately, it's not possible when you use these functions. Of course, we can generate the JSON with simple concatenate operators but do you really need it?

Comment: yes I need it pls

Comment: Ok, then concatenate the columns and the labels while caring about order and JSON stuff. For example: select area, CONCAT( '[{"source":"', source, '"},')

Answer (score 0):

So the complete answer is:

```
WITH lex AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('One', 'modak', 'good', 2021)
    v(area, source, type, date)
)
SELECT l.area,
    ARRAY_AGG(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('source', l.source, 'period', OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('type', l.type, 'date', l.date))) as sources
FROM lex AS l
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

which gives:

| AREA | SOURCES |
| --- | --- |
| One | [ { "period": { "date": 2021, "type": "good" }, "source": "modak" } ] |

Gokhan's answer show how to build a static array with [ARRAY_CONSTRUCT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_construct.html), but if you have a dynamic input like:

```
WITH lex AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    ('One', 'modak', 'good', 2021),
    ('One', 'modak', 'bad', 2022),
    ('Two', 'modak', 'good', 2021)
    v(area, source, type, date)
)
```

And you want, the below, you will need to use [ARRAY_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html)

| AREA | SOURCES |
| --- | --- |
| One | [ { "period": { "date": 2021, "type": "good" }, "source": "modak" }, { "period": { "date": 2022, "type": "bad" }, "source": "modak" } ] |
| Two | [ { "period": { "date": 2021, "type": "good" }, "source": "modak" } ] |

Comment: thanks alot for your answer.. Im hoping I can change the order of the json. for example  'source' before the 'period'

Comment: JSON has no order. If it was an array sure order can have meaning.